# Upload 3 GB document using apache HttpClient 4.1.2

Tags: java, apache, apache-httpclient-4.x

We are using HttpClient 4.1.2. 
When we try to upload a document to the server, which is working good if we try to upload a document of size less than 2 GB, If I upload more than 2 GB document then I see the error below..

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.OutputRecord.writeBuffer(OutputRecord.java:297)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.OutputRecord.write(OutputRecord.java:286)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecordInternal(SSLSocketImpl.java:743)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:731)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:59)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.write(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:153)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:114)
    at org.apache.commons.io.output.ProxyOutputStream.write(ProxyOutputStream.java:90)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1859)
```

Please find the code below:

```
try {
    // Requires a multi-part post
    MultipartEntity requestEntity = new MultipartEntity();
    post.setEntity(requestEntity);

    requestEntity.addPart(MIME_TYPE_NAME, new StringBody(mimeType));

    requestEntity.addPart(USER_ID_PARAMETER, new StringBody(loginUser
            .getUserid().toLowerCase()));
    requestEntity.addPart(USER_PASSWORD_PARAMETER, new StringBody(
            loginUser.getPassword()));

    requestEntity.addPart(DOCUMENT_PART_NAME,
            new ProgressReportingFileBody(filePath, uploadListener));

    post.getParams().setBooleanParameter(
            CoreProtocolPNames.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, true);

    // Find out what happened with the request
    HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext();
    // Add AuthCache to the execution context
    context.setAttribute(ClientContext.AUTH_CACHE, authCache);
    // Perform the POST
    setCurrentRequest(post);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(targetHost, post,
            context);
    // Get the response back
    message = response.getEntity();

    // Ensure the middleware returned an acceptable response
    checkError(response, context);
    checkInterrupted(post);

    Header documentId = response.getFirstHeader("DOCUMENT_ID");

    oDoc.sMimeType = mimeType;

} catch (ClientProtocolException ex) {
    throw new IwException(-3, "HTTP Error: " + ex.getMessage(),
            ex.toString());
} catch (IOException ex) {
    checkInterrupted(post);
    log.error("Failed to Upload Document", ex);
    throw new IwException(-3, "Upload Document Error: "
            + ex.getMessage(), ex.toString());
} finally {
    try {
        if (message != null) {
            // Clean up to allow another HTTP client call
            EntityUtils.consume(message);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        log.error("Failed to Close HTTP Connection", ex);
    }
}
```

Any ideas what it could be / would be great! Thanks for your time.

Comment: The peer is the server... This is likely not a problem of the client.

Comment: We are using WebSphere 8.

Comment: Thanks for your response Owlstead. What change at the server side would resolve this issue?

Comment: Is this supported by your OS, filesystem? 2 Gb limit used to be quite common for these.

Comment: Traditional Java HTTP libraries and Java HTTP API are not recommended for upload of large file. Either use an I/O oriented framework ([Netty](http://netty.io/)) are a different approach (i.e not http). EDIT: large file means > 2GB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upload in chunks, each having size of 256 Mb or about. Join on the sever side. On the programming level, this is easy to do. Also, uploading 3 Gb probably takes very long. In case of failure, it makes sense to have possibility to retry with smaller chunk.

Comment: Smaller sized chunks will be more practical as the HTTP overhead request size is small relative to it.

Comment: Thank you Audrius. I do accept this as one alternative. We have all kinds of documents (like video, jpeg or any format). Not sure how we are going to split any kind of document?

Comment: The content will not be lost if you later join the chunks correctly, independently on the content itself. You do not need to know or care about the actual document format.